# Excel VBA Object Variable Not Set issue, possible improper Redim usage?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am running into an error with the below code. When I debug, I find the line causing my problem:

```
Options(a) = New Element
```

The error displayed is Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set. With msg boxes I have found the value of a to be 0 at the time of the crash and the TotalItems to be 7. The Element object initialization is empty. I call the PopulateChildren method from another method within the same class. Am I using ReDim improperly? It seems like maybe it isn't increasing the size of my array... I have noticed examples of using it like this...

```
ReDim Preserve Options(0 to TotalItems)
```

...but it doesn't seem to do any different when I try it. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
Dim Options() As Element
Dim TotalItems As Integer
Dim Children(100) As Integer

Private Sub PopulateChildren()
    ReDim Preserve Options(TotalItems)
    For a = 0 To TotalItems - 1
        Options(a) = New Element
        Options(a).Populate (Children(a))
    Next a
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Element` is Object, you should use `Set`:

```
Set Options(a) = New Element
```

Comment: And if you are worried about whether your array indexing starts at 0 or 1, add `Option Base 0` to the top of the module so you are sure that `a=0` is a valid index.

Comment: @Floris, except when you use a `Split` it will always start from 0 whether you have `Option Base 0` or `Option Base 1`.  I know there is no `Split`used here but just saying :)

Comment: I always specify my arrays lower/upper bounds explicitly in VBA. I've been burned way too many times. In fact, I've started even using `lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)` when iterating through an array, too

Comment: Bah, just found a bug from pre-doing-this-time because I did an `1 to ubound` mistake. Good timing to post this comment, I guess..

Answer (score 0):

easy, put your dim options inside the SUB, or ...

```
public dim options()

sub ...
'your code
end sub
```

of course options doesn't exit for your sub like you wrote it ! so the error showing...